# RESTEASY - returning the same object with and without a list

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, resteasy

I have a bean that includes several properties and a list. E.g.

```
public class Person {
    @XmlElement
    public String getName() { }

    @XmlElement
    public List getFriends() { }
}
```

I now want to have an interface that sometimes returns a list of Persons with their friends sometimes without:

```
@GET
@Path("getPersonOnly")
public List<Person> getPersonOnly();

@GET
@Path("getPersonWithFriends")
public List<Person> getPersonWithFriends();
```

The implementation of these methods is very similar. The only difference is that one of them will not include in the xml returned the list of friends.

Any ideas on how to solve this? My initial thought was to subclass Person to PersonWithNoFriends which will not have the getFriends annotated.

Thanks,

Assaf

Comment: Is the Friends element omitted from the XML if getFriends() returns null instead of an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

In your getPersonOnly(), load the person, setFriends to NULL and the element won't be in the output.